# Selecting feature clusters in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

At the moment I have my map set up to cluster icons upon zooming out. I want to disable the ability to select clusters but allow the user to select individual markers if they zoom in. Preferably, clicking on a cluster should select each individual feature in the cluster (in their correct locations). My select code is like so:

```
var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    style: selectedMarkerStyle,
    addCondition: function(mapBrowserEvent){
        var features = null;
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(mapBrowserEvent.pixel, function (feature_, layer) {
            features = feature_.values_.features;
        });
        if(features !== null && features.length > 1){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
map.addInteraction(selectClick);
```

I tried to make the addCondition check if multiple features are located at the point and then stop the event however it doesn't seem to be working. At the moment clicking on a cluster selects one of the features in the cluster, in the location of the cluster, rather than the features correct location. Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks